# Echo Text from php Webpage

Tags: php

I have some Text in a web page that i need to echo in my php page'.

If the text is like this

```
"translatedText":"Ciao mondo"
```

I use this php code

```
<?php 
$tr=translatedText; 
$Text=file_get_contents("http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?langpair=en|it&q=Hello%20World!"); 
$regex = "/".$tr."=\"([^\"]+)\"/"; 
preg_match_all($regex,$Text,$Match); 
$fid=$Match[1][0]; 
echo $fid; 
?>
```

The result it good

```
Ciao mondo
```

But if the text is like This

```
{"translatedText":"Ciao mondo"}
```

I don't have any result
How to extract the

> Ciao mondo

text from there?

Comment: That looks like JSON output, try PHP's `json_decode()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), but decode to array:

```
<?php
$response = file_get_contents('http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?langpair=en|it&q=Hello%20World!');
$array = json_decode($response,1);

echo $array['responseData']['translatedText'];
```

You can also:

```
var_dump($array);
```

To see how this whole array looks like.

Comment: I edited my php code. i tried your code but no result

Answer (score 0):

**Use [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)**

```
$var = '{"translatedText":"Ciao mondo"}';

var_dump(json_decode($var));
```

***Output:***

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["translatedText"]=>
  string(10) "Ciao mondo"
}
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://codepad.org/N3X8E3SU)

OR without `stdClass`;

```
  var_dump(json_decode($var, true));
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://codepad.org/HYrd5o7s)

***output***

```
array(1) {
  ["translatedText"]=>
  string(10) "Ciao mondo"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of structure is named [JSON](http://www.php.net/json) and is not just about strings.

```
...
$tr = json_decode($Text,TRUE);
echo $tr["translatedText"];
...
```

You need to verify that the string is enclosed on `{..}` otherwise your JSON would not been valid, thus decoding will fail.

**UPDATE**

Based on the JSON you receive, you should do this:

```
$tr = json_decode($Text,TRUE);
echo $tr["responseData"]["translatedText"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_decode:

```
$Text = json_decode($Text);
echo $Text['translatedText'];
```

or assuming the curly brackets occur only as first and last characters of your string, you can try this before your `preg_match_all`:

```
echo substr($Text, 1, -1);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use [JSON_DECODE](https://www.php.net/json_decode)

```
<?php

$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345

?>
```